# hadoop MapR2 job no action

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

```
ayush@ayush-Inspiron-3521:~/apps/h260$ jps
3474 ResourceManager
3603 NodeManager
3316 SecondaryNameNode
3957 Jps
3129 DataNode
2975 NameNode


ayush@ayush-Inspiron-3521:~/apps/h260$ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user

ayush@ayush-Inspiron-3521:~/apps/h260$ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/ayush

ayush@ayush-Inspiron-3521:~/apps/h260$ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /input

ayush@ayush-Inspiron-3521:~/apps/h260$ bin/hdfs dfs -put input/ /input

ayush@ayush-Inspiron-3521:~/apps/h260$ bin/hadoop jar example.jar Firstjoin /input output

ayush@ayush-Inspiron-3521:~/apps/h260$ jps
3474 ResourceManager
3603 NodeManager
3316 SecondaryNameNode
3129 DataNode
4206 Jps
2975 NameNode
```

no output or error i.e there's no action happened
i have `example.jar` with my `Firstjoin` class and an hdfs input directory
also and copied file to it also.
any suggesion 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1.First check the jar is runnable jar or normal jar
2.If this is a normal jar then you may have to provide package name as well if package exists
3.If it is a runnable jar make sure that while creating runnable jar you point to driverclass/main class.
4.If above two is not the issue check by typing `hadoop dfs -ls /`  and check if the directory shows or not.
5.Try formating the namenode and restarting the cluster again...
Let me know if anyof this works..

Comment: it has been resoved.....formatting namenode does this.....but still cant get what was happened there!     thanks.

Comment: Are you using ubuntu??I guess I found similar issue in ubuntu...then I changed it to centos